# how to efficiently compress a long list of file path strings one by one?

Tags: python, linux, algorithm, python-3.x, compression

I have a very long (>1M) list of file path strings. I need to compress these strings individually to save space. A path can be quite long, e.g. 150 chars.

Many of the paths have a common prefix, which would improve compression, **if** I only could compress them as a bulk.

Experimenting with `gzip` and `zip`, I get 16% compression on one string, 85% on 1000 strings, which is expected.

Is there a way to "teach" the algorithm what the data distribution is upfront, or have a "learning" algorithm which improves the compression over subsequent applications?

I need this as a library, no time to develop my own at the moment. I suppose a trie would be of help here.

Comment: This is too broad! Think about bijectivity a bit and the effects on the necessary ordering of your accesses (encoder and decoder need to be synchronized). (i also think ppmd-based compressors will achieve higher ratios; at the cost of being symmetric)

Comment: You may want to make use of a [Patricia trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_tree).

Comment: @Herb thanks. Do you know of any ready implementation, in Python or anything?